# node.js passport local strategy problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am new to node.js in general and passport in particular.
I have exposed a passport configuration in a file by itself like the following:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/User');

var messages = {
    100: 'Username and/or password are not correct.',
    101: 'User already exists.'
};

module.exports = function (passport) {

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {

    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', messages['100']));
        }
        user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', messages['100']));
            }
        });
    });
}));}
```

in my node routes, i am doing the following to handle the login scenario:

```
app.post('/login',function(req, res, next){
    console.log('loggin in ')
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
        console.log('allo');
        console.log(err);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info)
    });
});
```

however I am not getting a response; can you please clarify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are not getting a response, but what kind of messages are you getting? More information would help me know where to start looking. Also, add the express logger to your server so you can see what kind of routes are being requested and the HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return** the **object** ***returned*** by `passport.authenticate`

```
app.post('/login',function(req, res, next){
    console.log('loggin in ')
/**/return passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
        console.log('allo');
        console.log(err);
        console.log(user);
        console.log(info)
    })(req, res, next);
});
```